# In filtering data source, I'm getting error "parameter named 'p__linq__0' already exists" (LightSwitch)

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

On my lightswitch application, I have a table called, "Transactions". This table has a column named "owners". Owners column contains usernames which are separated by comma, like "username1,username2,username3". In filtering Transactions records, I want to show only the records that the current user is one of the owners.

For this purpose I used he following code.

```
partial void Transactions_Filter(ref Expression<Func<Transaction, bool>> filter)
    {
        filter = e => e.owners.Contains(this.Application.User.Name);
    }
```

But i get an error, "A parameter named 'p__linq__0' already exists in the parameter collection. Parameter names must be unique in the parameter collection. Parameter name: parameter"

Any suggestion to fix the error?

Comment: Are you using a MySQL database with LightSwitch?

Comment: In that case, and assuming you see the error when the filter executes, I would inspect the generated SQL query by using either SQL's in built profiler (if you're using the full version) or the freely available [Express Profiler](https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com).  If you can post the generated SQL this may help provide a clue to the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use this.Application.User.Name as a parameter in other method which is compiled before Filter method?

In addition i think you should use a child table to save user names instead of put all in a columns. In lightswitch, if you design database well you will have a good application.

Comment: I think in _filter() function, I could use operators like ==, <=, >= and similar to these. Maybe _filter() function doesn't support 'like' or 'contain'. I ended up creating a query and using _PreprocessQuery() function, instead.

Comment: I don't think so. Fitler is a boolean expression so you can use any linq boolean method to build that. The error message showed clearly cause came from parameter in SQL query. Do you have 2 or more method which was named Transactions_Filter in your code?